# Where do i store and add Hindi/Devanagari Suggestions in Android Custom Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

> As i have mentioned above  in the Title.
> I have created the Layout and design but iam confused where to store and how to implement the sugesstions part in Hindi language in my custom keyboard
> any help and helpful materials i would appreciate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the permission in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
```

Then you will have to add the words, here locale is the main key. Locale can be selected as hindi, if you want to save the word in hindi.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, "Mad", 
  Locale.getDefault());
}else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
  UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, 
  UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE_TYPE_CURRENT);
 }
```